# Excel error message"one or more named invalid references"

Tags: excel, vba

I cannot find the named range or reference that is invalid, according to Excel. I checked my named ranges, including ranges within charts. The excel file contains a macro that creates a report that works fine when launched within the file itself. However, if I call that function from *another* workbook to run the report that is when I get the error message of invalid references. When going through the reports created both directly and indirectly they seem identical. Setting `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` does not work.

I tried using the code below from from [Allen Wyatt](https://excelribbon.tips.net/T008664_Tracking_Down_Invalid_References.html) to go through all reference and none refer to outside sheets nor contain any errors.

```vb
    Sub CheckReferences()
    ' Check for possible missing or erroneous links in
    ' formulas and list possible errors in a summary sheet

      Dim iSh As Integer
      Dim sShName As String
      Dim sht As Worksheet
      Dim c, sChar As String
      Dim rng As Range
      Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
      Dim wks As Worksheet
      Dim sChr As String, addr As String
      Dim sFormula As String, scVal As String
      Dim lNewRow As Long
      Dim vHeaders

      vHeaders = Array("Sheet Name", "Cell", "Cell Value", "Formula")
      'check if 'Summary' worksheet is in workbook
      'and if so, delete it
      With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
      End With

      For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
        If Worksheets(i).Name = "Summary" Then
          Worksheets(i).Delete
        End If
      Next i

      iSh = Worksheets.Count

      'create a new summary sheet
        Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(iSh)
        Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = "Summary"
      With Sheets("Summary")
        Range("A1:D1") = vHeaders
      End With
      lNewRow = 2

      ' this will not work if the sheet is protected,
      ' assume that sheet should not be changed; so ignore it
      On Error Resume Next

      For i = 1 To iSh
        sShName = Worksheets(i).Name
        Application.Goto Sheets(sShName).Cells(1, 1)
        Set rng = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 23)

        For Each c In rng
          addr = c.Address
          sFormula = c.Formula
          scVal = c.Text

          For j = 1 To Len(c.Formula)
            sChr = Mid(c.Formula, j, 1)

            If sChr = "[" Or sChr = "!" Or _
              IsError(c) Then
              'write values to summary sheet
              With Sheets("Summary")
                .Cells(lNewRow, 1) = sShName
                .Cells(lNewRow, 2) = addr
                .Cells(lNewRow, 3) = scVal
                .Cells(lNewRow, 4) = "'" & sFormula
              End With
              lNewRow = lNewRow + 1
              Exit For
            End If
          Next j
        Next c
      Next i

    ' housekeeping
      With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
      End With

    ' tidy up
      Sheets("Summary").Select
      Columns("A:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit
      Range("A1:D1").Font.Bold = True
      Range("A2").Select
    End Sub
```

Comment: Your code is probably using `ActiveWorkbook` rather than `ThisWorkbook`

Comment: Where does your error pop up? Thought I think it might be a reference problem, you are not fully qualifying your ranges, you need to reference workbooks when working with more than one.

Comment: I am not using `ActiveWorkbook` in my code. I do not know how to determine when the error pops up because when I run it from the original workbook it runs without error and if I run it stepwise indirectly through another workbook it also runs without errors. The error is only reported when I run the whole code indirectly. The report workbook works in a vacuum. The only thing my other workbook is doing is calling the sub in my report workbook. There are no ranges that are defined outside the scope of the report workbook.

Comment: @BlackBear please have a look to my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57218299/11167163) this mighe solve your issue if it don't give the try to the addin I suggested.

Comment: @BlackBear You're using `ActiveWorkbook` implicitly, whenever you don't Fully Qualify your objects:  `For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count` - since you haven't specified the Workbook, it **defaults to `ActiveWorkbook`**, so this line is treated as `For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count` - and the same with `With Sheets("Summary")` (i.e. `With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Summary")`).  So, I suspect that π is correct

Comment: @chronocidal Indeed, however that is only the case for the code I posted above. My own code is always specified to handle the workbook I am working in. The code I posted is the error handling code I used to try and find missing references, but it did not return with anything missing.

Comment: @BlackBear And how, exactly, are we supposed to help you locate potential issues in your code if you're not posting it?

Comment: There is way too much code to post. If there was a way to determine where the error occured it would help.

Comment: @BlackBear Do you have any `#REF!` entries in the [name manager](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-the-name-manager-in-excel-4d8c4c2b-9f7d-44e3-a3b4-9f61bd5c64e4)? In the workbook that contains the code, and in the workbook that calls the code?

Comment: @BlackBear Add `Debug.Print` labels throughout the code.  When the job fails, you can look at what the last label to fail was, what the next label is, and the error is between those.  If nothing else, you could use this for a Binary Search method

Comment: @GSerg There are no `#REF` in either workbook. At least not before I run the code. and after I run the code. I am not sure if there is an intermittent step that causes it, but the data turns out fine regardless.

Comment: @Chronocidal The job doesn't fail. The file is generated seemingly correctly, it is only when executed through an external source that the error message pops after all the code is execeuted and the file correctly generated. I will try to add some debug labels and see if anything pops up.